# Given the same index, are iword() and pword() guaranteed to refer to separate underlying values?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, xalloc

In the standard C++ `ios` library, is it guaranteed that `&stream.iword(ind) != &stream.pword(ind)` when called on the same `stream` with the same `ind` value?

Moreover, is it guaranteed that I can use the `void*` and `long` values individually given the same index (i.e. they're not implemented as a union, etc.)?

I suppose the X-Y problem here is how do I know if, given a random stream, my custom value ("allocated" using `xalloc()`) has been initialized? I ask because I've seen people use `pword()` to check a magic constant and then `iword()` to initialize that value if the previous condition fails.

I mainly care about C++11 and onward, though any relevant historical information is welcome.

Comment: The reference returned by `iword()` is invalidated when you call `pword()`, so I'm not sure the addresses can be meaningfully compared.

Comment: @Cornstalks Interesting; how is it invalidated? Do you mean you can either use `pword()` or `iword()`, but not both?

Comment: Here's some (non-authoritative, but very useful) documentation on [`iword`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) and [`pword`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/pword). For both of those methods, notice the sentence *"The reference may be invalidated by any operation on this `ios_base` object[...]"*. You can use either one, but once you call the next function, you need to discard your old reference and not use it any more. Think of it like taking the address of an object in a `std::vector`. That's fine, but once you call `push_back` that address could be invalidated.

Comment: @Cornstalks I see -- but ultimately, is the underlying (referred-to) value the same for both `pword()` and `iword()` or are they two separate, concrete values that can be modified individually?

Comment: The standard guarantees that `iword` and `pword` access separate, independently allocated blocks of storage. The two functions must behave as if `std::ios_base` has two members, `long* iarray` and `void** parray`, with `iword` manipulating the former and `pword` the latter ([**\[ios.base.storage\]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios.base.storage))

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you :) Mind making an answer out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard says that `iword()` and `pword()` should behave as if they are manipulating two separate, independent blocks of storage - rather than, say, a single block whose contents are interpreted as `long` sometimes and `void*` other times.

> **[ios.base]**
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>   class ios_base {
>   // ...
>   private:
>     long* iarray; // exposition only
>     void** parray; // exposition only
>   };
> }
> ```

---

> **[ios.base.storage]/3**
>
> ```
>   long& iword(int idx);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* If `iarray` is a null pointer, allocates an array of `long` of unspecified size and stores a pointer to its first element in `iarray`. The function then extends the array pointed at by `iarray` as necessary to include the element `iarray[idx]`. Each newly allocated element of the array is initialized to zero. The reference returned is invalid after any other operations on the object. However, the value of the storage referred to is retained, so that until the next call to `copyfmt`, calling `iword` with the same index yields another reference to the same value...

**[ios.base.storage]/5** repeats the exact same wording, substituting `pword` for `iword`, `parray` for `iarray` and `void*` for `long`.

The important part is "the value of the storage ... is retained" - a subsequent `iword` call with a given index should see the value that was written into the storage that the previous `iword` call with the same index provided a reference to, regardless of intervening method calls (other than `copyfmt`), even if that intervening method call is `pword` (and vice versa).